# Unable to compile jrxml containing highchart component with JasperCompileManager.compileReport()

Tags: java, highcharts, jasper-reports

I would like to compile a jrxml containing a highchart component (jasper pro) using Java.
Therefore I created a build.gradle with all the dependencies it requires.
My dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-beanutils', name: 'commons-beanutils', version: '1.9.3'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2.2'
    compile group: 'commons-digester', name: 'commons-digester', version: '2.1'
    compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:6.3.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '**/*.jar')
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.1'
    compile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-2"
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.4'
    compile group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: '1.2'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.4'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.4'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.mozilla', name: 'rhino', version: '1.7.7.1'
    compile group: 'jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.0.13'
    compile group: 'org.olap4j', name: 'olap4j', version: '1.2.0'
    compile group: 'bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk14', version: '1.50'
    compile group: 'com.lowagie', name: 'itext', version: '2.1.7'
}
```

The JasperReports pro libraries are located in lib.

But I got stuck when compiling as it says the license file is invalid.

I am using my jasperserver.licence file, but somehow it is not capable in reading it properly

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error compiling report design.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:247)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:357)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:290)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:575)
at ch.prospective.jasperreports.wekklyreports.WeeklyReports.fetch report(WeeklyReports.groovy:16)
Caused by: com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.LicenseException: License is in invalid state
at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.BaseLicenseProviderImpl.requireLicense(BaseLicenseProviderImpl.java:189)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.BaseLicenseProviderImpl.requireFeature(BaseLicenseProviderImpl.java:196)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.LicenseManager.requireFeature(LicenseManager.java:113)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.HighChartsUtils.requireHighchartsFeature(HighChartsUtils.java:43)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.StandardChartComponent.(StandardChartComponent.java:73)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartCompiler.toCompiledComponent(ChartCompiler.java:69)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseComponentElement.(JRBaseComponentElement.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseObjectFactory.visitComponentElement(JRBaseObjectFactory.java:1736)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignComponentElement.visit(JRDesignComponentElement.java:105)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractObjectFactory.getVisitResult(JRAbstractObjectFactory.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseElementGroup.(JRBaseElementGroup.java:83)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseBand.(JRBaseBand.java:84)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseObjectFactory.getBand(JRBaseObjectFactory.java:533)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.(JRBaseReport.java:242)
```

Does someone have got experience in this ?

I've linked the whole project to this question as zip file. Just extract and run.

The zip file can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zvbjgehtnfc1wn/jasper-reports-with-highcharts.zip?dl=0

Simply call

```
gradle test
```

or run the testcase within your IDE.

Comment: Post the JRXML file.

Comment: @Detlef Did you try to debug using the source code?